# Can't enter BIOS right away

Tags: windows-10, boot, keyboard, bios

My "USB legacy devices" is enabled in BIOS. But pressing the <kbd>Del</kbd> key to enter the BIOS doesn't work the first time around - ever. This is what I have to do to enter my BIOS:

1. Reboot. On the first long beep, continually press the <kbd>Del</kbd> key.
   The system ignores the <kbd>Del</kbd> press and the windows circle thing starts turning.
   (P.S.: The keyboard power light does NOT turn on at this point)
2. Hard reboot to try again.
   On the third attempt, naturally, the "Starting Recovery mode" kicks in.
   I ignore it and continue with a hard reboot again.
3. On the 5th or 6th hard reboot, the system goes into a boot-loop with one SHORT beep. So, computer reboots, MB is displayed, one short beep, and system reboots itself.
4. On the 4th or 5th short-beep reboot, there will be a normal, long beep, and then my <kbd>Del</kbd> key will enter the BIOS.

Other than this issue, my computer works great, with no BSODs or any other issues.

Can someone tell me why this happens and how I can fix this so that on every reboot, the <kbd>Del</kbd> key will work right away on the first attempt? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a USB keyboard? Connecting keyboard with a PS/2 converter will enable the keyboard to be used while booting. Usually USB keyboards work while booting but on some of the motherboards they don't. So, try connecting it with a PS/2 connector

Comment: I don't need to go to the BIOS often, just when I do it was frustrating. I already finished doing what I needed today but next time I'll connect a USB-PS/2 adaptor to my keyboard (which I have) and update if it helped.